# Is there any way to summarize by multiple groups of factors?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am searching a way to extract a mode of a colume ("meteo2") by multiple groups ("season", "meteo") that are factor format in my dataframe, "mydf". Here is my test code as below, but which does not work resulting an error message. With one group, "season", it works. Three columns all have "NA" values. I am not sure which part is wrong in my code. Any help is very much welcomed!

```
str(mydf$season)
Factor w/ 4 levels "Spring","Summer",...:
 str(mydf$meteo)
Factor w/ 7 levels "<40","<50","<60",..: 
str(mydf$meteo2)
Factor w/ 4 levels "E","N","S","W": 

# mode function
Mode = function(x){ 
ta = table(x)
tam = max(ta)
if (all(ta == tam))
     mod = NA
else
     if(is.numeric(x))
mod = as.numeric(names(ta)[ta == tam])
else
     mod = names(ta)[ta == tam]
return(mod)}

# extracting mode
dataSummary<-mydf %>% select(season, meteo, meteo2) %>%
mutate(meteo = forcats::fct_explicit_na(meteo)) %>%
group_by(meteo, season) %>%
summarise(m=Mode(meteo2))

dataSummary
error : Column `m` can't promote group 30 to character
```

Here is my sample data.

```
dput(head(mydf_sample))
structure(list(season = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Spring", 
"Summer", "Fall", "Winter"), class = "factor"), meteo2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("E", "N", "S", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    meteo = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("<40", 
    "<50", "<60", "<70", "<75", "<80", "80+"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("season", 
"meteo2", "meteo"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` ? `dput(mydf)` ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I posted my sample data, not a full data, because I tried, but  it is too long to post.

Comment: but this seems to work on your sample data `mydf_sample %>% 
  group_by(meteo, season) %>%
  summarise(m=Mode(meteo2))`

Comment: > mydf_sample %>% group_by(meteo, season) %>% summarise(m=Mode(meteo2))
error: Column `m` can't promote group 28 to character
warnings: 
Factor `meteo` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
>  ## I see this message.. ##

Comment: Can you try `mydf_sample %>% 
  group_by(meteo, season) %>%
  summarise(m= as.character(Mode(meteo2)))` ?

Comment: @user2928318 I have updated my answer to include the NA conversion. But this is just a warning. Did you see an output?

Comment: Thank you, Ronak and mcskinner! Your codes are working well! Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug was not reproduced with the sample data.

But if your goal is to produce the mode, this is possible more directly by counting the combinations and taking the most common one.

```r
mydf %>%
  mutate(meteo = forcats::fct_explicit_na(meteo)) %>%
  count(meteo, season, meteo2) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  distinct(meteo, season, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Calling [distinct](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html) will take the first option it sees, which is the most common because of the descending order from [arrange](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html).

That will only pick one of the options in the case of ties. If that is a concern, you can select everything with a bit of tweaking.

```r
mydf %>%
  mutate(meteo = forcats::fct_explicit_na(meteo)) %>%
  count(meteo, season, meteo2) %>%
  group_by(meteo, season) %>%
  filter(n == max(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mcskinner! It seems to work! Additionally, is there a way to see the whole results? I see just a part of it. "A tibble:31 x 3 .... with 21 more rows".

Comment: Great! You can see more rows, but first I would recommend saving the answer to a variable: `summary <- mydf %>% ...`. Then you can print more rows easily without recomputing: `print(summary, n=100)`. You can increase `n` to `nrow(summary)` to print the whole thing, but this may be very large.

That would show 100 rows, but you can do more.

Comment: @user2928318 great! I am very glad to hear that everything is working for you. When you have a moment, would you mind accepting one of these answers so that future browsers know where to look?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems that some groups are not returning character values (probably `NA` which is of class logical). You can explicitly turn them to character by using `as.character`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf_sample %>% group_by(meteo,season) %>% summarise(m=as.character(Mode(meteo2)))
```